# Lucene is not finding results that are present in the index

Tags: search, lucene, luke

I'm inspecting a Lucene index with Luke.

All documents have a field 'Title' and I would like to do a search for the search expression Title:Power, by which I want to find all documents with a title containing the word `Power`.

In Luke, I go to the tab "Search" and enter `+Title:Power`

When searching, there are no results. However, when I search by another field, I do find the document: `+ContentType:MyContentType`

In the column `Title`, I can clearly see the value of the document being: `Power Quality Guide`.

What could  be the reasons I'm not finding this document when searching on Title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be a number of reasons. Most common ones:

- `Title` field could just be stored in the index but not indexed for search (`Field.Store.YES`, `Field.Index.NO`), unlike for the field for which you can find results (`ContentType`);
- document(s) could be indexed using one analyzer but query is using a different one;
- document is indexed using `NOT_ANALYZED` option which would store a field as a single term